# How to connect two networks via Cloud in GNS3?

Tags: gns3

I have these two networks in GNS3 I am working on for a lab.

[image]

I want to be able to connect R7 to the cloud and R30 to the cloud and have them communicate with their static IPs and be able to ping through eachother's networks as well as use RIP-related stuff (thats the aim of the lab).

Does anyone know how I may do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple to do it.
Insert a cloud (C1) and at the NIO UDP tab within cloud add a currently un used port for local and listening port say 40000 and 50000 respectively. And connect this C1 to R7. 
In the cloud that's already connected to R30 (I'll call it C2) add an NIO UDP with the local and listening port 50000 and 40000 respectively and reconnect it to this NIO. The local port of C1 becomes the listening port of C2 and vice versa.

We're done. Now the routers R7 and R30 will behave like they are connected directly with a cable.

Make sure you Check for the unused ports with netstat -a command.